# jquery select adding extra rows

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a small ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: 'inc/getfunctions.php?q='+l_id+'&func=load_po',
            success:function(data){
                //alert ('hi');
                if (data.po_num) {
                $('#po_num_s').append($('<option>').text('Select a PO').attr('value', 0));
                 var po_num  = data.po_num;
                 var $subType = $("#po_num_s");
                 $.each(data, function () {
                  $subType.append($('<option></option>').attr("value", data.l_id).text(data.po_num));
                });
                }
            }
            });
```

it is apending 2 rows :

`<'option value="11">112212<'/option>`

`<'option value="11">112212<'/option>`

is the output
Thanks in advance

Comment: i want only 1 choice, its only in the database once

Comment: Have you tried it without the .each function?

Comment: show your html part and json response of ajax call

Comment: Based off the javascript, the data object looks like: `{po_num: "value", l_id: "value"}`. You don't need to loop for that. The `.each` will loop through each property of the object, which is why it shows twice.

Comment: try console.log(data) and write to us

Comment: so how would loop through if there is more than record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $.each function will take an array or an object and iterate over its items, while providing the item key and value as parameters to the callback. Like so:

```
$.each(["aaaa", "bb", "ccc"], function(key, value){
   console.log(value.length);
});

// Will output: 
// 4
// 2
// 3
```

But you aren't using the each-loop for something useful, as you don't receive any item in the callback function. The only reason you're getting as few as 2 lines is that your `data` object only has 2 keys in it. Try adding another property to `data` at the same place as your commented alert, like so:

```
......
success:function(data){
    //alert ('hi');
    data.foo = "bar"
    if (data.po_num) {
......
```

and watch the each-loop go three rounds.